# How can I know which function is a Cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, functions

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXmsM.jpg)
I know the condition of being a function to be cdf but I couldn't verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option cannot be a CDF, because the CDF of a constant variable equal to $3$ [would be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g#Examples) $0$ for $x\lt3$, not $x\le3$. The second isn't because it's negative either on $[0,\,1)$ or $(1,\,3)$, depending on the sign of $k$.